# Leaflet map doesn't load with angular-leaflet-directive

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I directly copied and pasted the source code, from this webpage, onto my compiler: http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/basic/first-example

I included the following source files within my HTML file :

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/angular-leaflet-directive.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />

<script src="http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/dist/angular-leaflet-directive.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-leaflet/bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"/>
```

The map doesn't load, as seen in this image below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before using angular-leaflet-directive, you must include some files to your project (.css and .js).

Try to follow  [those steps](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-leaflet/#!/getting-started) :

Comment: Thanks - is it okay if I include all those files (.css and.js) in the same directory? My main HTML file is under a file called AngularTestFile - can I include all those .css and ,js files under AngularTestFile as well?

Comment: Ok - What's the significance of "//" and "/" in the script tag (i.e., from //unpkg.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.js and //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js)?